# react native redux mapStateToProps state updating but not re-rendering presenter component

Tags: react-native, redux, react-redux

Having problem where the state in `mapDispatchToProps` appears to be updating, yet the component does not re-render to reflect these changes, even though...

- presenter component is correctly connected to redux actions (can successfully *initialize* props via `mapDispatchToProps` and call `mapDispatchToProps` functions, in any case)
- the redux reducer that handles the redux action called is updating the state immutably (making me doubt that that is the problem (https://github.com/reduxjs/redux/issues/2190#issuecomment-271109542)), ie. the reducer code looks like

```
const initialState = {
    session: {
        ...
        toUpdate: {success: false, processing: false, message: ''},
        ...
    },
    someOtherStateSections: {...},
    ...
}

const sessionReducer = (state=initialState.session, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        ...
        case Types.ACTION_TO_HANDLE:
                console.log(`REDUCER: ACTION_TO_HANDLE: check that state is being updating with intended values:\n${JSON.stringify(action, null, 2)}`)
                return Object.assign({}, state, {toUpdate: {
                    success: action.success,
                    processing: action.processing,
                    message: action.message,
                }})
        ...
    }
}

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
    session: sessionReducer,
    ...
})

export default rootReducer;
```

- After updating from the reducer, logging statements appear to show that the `state` arg. in the `mapStateToProps` function is updating to reflect these changes. The code snippet look like

```
const mapStateToProps = (state, ownProps) => {
    console.log(`PickupLocationAnchorFormContainer: mapStateToProps: ${JSON.stringify(state.session.pickupLocationAnchorChangeStatus, null, 2)}`)
    return {
        toUpdate: state.session.toUpdate,
        ownProps: ownProps,
    }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch,) => {
  return {
    someThunk: (some, inputs) => {
      dispatch(someThunk(some, inputs))
    },
  }
}

const MyComponentContainer = connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(MyComponent)

export default MyComponentContainer
```

yet `MyComponent` does not seem to update its `this.props.toUpdate` to mach the updated redux store values.

- And the updated state values are different from the old values (in this example, `toUpdate.success` is set from `false` to `true`), making me doubt that the problem is related to shallow equality check (see https://redux.js.org/faq/reactredux#why-isnt-my-component-re-rendering-or-my-mapstatetoprops-running) (though have not been able to resolve the bug so far, so what do I know, right?)

Any further debugging suggestions or recommended solutions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try writing this in reducer instead:

```
const sessionReducer = (state=initialState, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        ...
        case Types.ACTION_TO_HANDLE:
                return Object.assign({}, state, {
                    ...state,
                    session: {
    ...state.session,
   toUpdate: {
                    success: action.success,
                    processing: action.processing,
                    message: action.message,
                },
           }
       })

    }
}
```

Comment: Away from code right now, but would you mind explaining your thought process as to what you think the problem may be and how this is intended to fix it? (And for anyone who may be thrown off by the use of ellipsis in this answer vs my use of `...` as a "yada yada" placeholder, see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax)

Comment: As per my thinking this happens because of the common mistake that instead of returning a copy of new state we make changes in the original state in reducer and return that state, this is called shallow copying due to which the redux thinks there is no change in state.

Comment: Am I not already doing that by returning `Object.assign({}, state, {toUpdate: ... })`? In the last bullet of my post, had shown why I though I was already accounting for a shallow copy error and linked to the docs for why I used `Object.assign()`.